# How Can Compress Audio In Call Recorder Android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I Used This Code Capture Audio In Android Studio
But Size Audio Its Big(1min=1MB)
How Can Compress Audio Without Quality loss

```
AudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
AudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
AudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
AudioRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
AudioRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(44100);
AudioRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(128000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the encoder to AMR_N8.  About 1 MB/sec sounds about right for that encoder.  If you want to compress it you can choose another encoding, such as Vorbis.

Please note that the different encoders have different purposes.  None of them will compress without quality loss-  we're converting analog sound to digital values, there is always quality loss with that.  Different encoders are optimized for different uses.  AMR is optimized for human voice.  It filters out frequencies not in vocal range.  That's a quality loss, but it may be one you want (like in a call).  You can't get everything-  you're going to have to sacrifice size or quality. I suggest you study up on the different encodings found at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html and figure out what's best for you.